# Как присвоить умному указателю новое значение

Tags: c++

```
int* ptr_1 = new int(10);
int* ptr_2 = new int(20);
std::unique_ptr<int> u_1 (ptr_1);
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы `u_1` указывал на `ptr_2`, не затирая данные в `ptr_1`.

При использовании `u_1.reset(ptr_2)` в `ptr_1` затираются данные

Comment: Сначала отказаться от владения с помощью `u_1.release()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Можно ли сделать так, чтобы u_1 указывал на ptr_2, не затирая данные в ptr_1.

```
int* old_ptr = u_1.release();
u_1.reset(ptr_2);
```

см. [std::unique_ptr<>::release](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release)